# How to find degree of field of extension of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose one is asked to find $[GF(2^{12}) : GF(2^3)]$, where $GF(p^n)$ denotes the unique finite field of order $p^n$. How do I go about solving this sort of problem?

Answer (score 5):

Recall that the degree $[L:K]$ of a field extension $L/K$ is just the *dimension* of $L$ as a $K$-vector space. If $n = [L:K] = \dim_K(L)$ is finite, then $L$ is isomorphic to $K^n$ as a $K$-vector space. If $K$ is finite, then $\#L = (\#K)^n$.

Answer (score 3):

If you have $\Bbb F\subseteq \Bbb K\subseteq \Bbb L$, with $\Bbb F,\Bbb K,\Bbb L$ fields, $\Bbb L$ an extension of $\Bbb K$ and $\Bbb K$ an extension of $\Bbb F$ then the [degrees formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees) tells you that $|\Bbb L :\Bbb F|=|\Bbb L: \Bbb K|\cdot|\Bbb K:\Bbb F|$.

In your particular case you have that $|GF(2^{12}):GF(2^{3})|=\frac{|GF(2^{12}):GF(2)|}{|GF(2^{3}):GF(2)|}=4$.

From here you can immediately prove the more general result $|GF(p^m):GF(p^n)|=\frac mn$ if $n| m$

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I'm quite rusty on my field theory, however. What result leads to $\vert GF(p^m) : GF(p) \vert = m$?

Comment: Actually, I think I see the solution. The elements of $GF(p^n)$ look like 
$$a_0 + a_1u +a_2u^2 + \cdots + a_{n-1}u^{n-1},$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Clearly then, $\left \{1, u, u^2, \cdots, u^{n-1} \right \}$ is a basis for $GF(p^n)$, the vector space of $GF(p^n)$ over $GF(p)$ has dimension $n$.

Comment: yeah, that seems good, it should be an immediate consequence of your construction of $GF(p^n)$, but there are different ways to do so @JaneDoe

Answer (score 2):

we have $[GF(2^{12}):GF(2)]=[GF(2^{12}):GF(2^3)][GF(2^{3}):GF(2)]$ then $12=[GF(2^{12}):GF(2^3)]\times 3$ therfore  $[GF(2^{12}):GF(2^3)]=4$